# put the JSON array data from fetch to dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build a simple app which will show a dropdown, the value of the dropdown gained from a fetch's return. Furthermore, I want to show the location only in the dropdown/picker/or any other component where I can pick 1 option.

Should I put the return in an array or anything?

When I console the return, it is like this

```
[
  {
    "ID": "BOGOR~10~522",
    "Location": "BOGOR"
  },
  {
    "ID": "JADETABEK~16~502",
    "Location": "JADETABEK"
  }
]
```

Here is the testing class

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { View , StyleSheet , Text , Dimensions , Picker } from 'react-native';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';
import { Item } from 'native-base';

const ScreenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const Screenheight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default class testing extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    } 

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({"lokasi":
                {

                }
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.PilihLokasiResult.Lokasi)
            this.setState({
                data: res.PilihLokasiResult.lokasi
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>

                    {this.state.data.map((index) => {
                        return(
                            <Dropdown/>
                        )
                    })}

            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
})
```

so now the data[] in the constructor has the value of the response like in the first box. but I don't know how to set the values of location to the dropdown item. can anyone help? thanks

this is the console.log(res)
[image: screenshoot]

Comment: https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown It waits for a `data` prop as an array. So, you need to pass an array for the options. You can create this array from your fetch result. I can't understand your other question, related to the "location" one. If you can explain it more clearly maybe someone can help.

Comment: when i call the fetch method, it will return a result where the value of
res.PilihLokasi.Lokasi is like the first box above. so i need the location value from the return, to be put to the dropdown item.

Comment: Do I get it right? Do you want an array including the `Location` values from the response to pass the `Dropdown` component right?

Comment: yeah, you're right..
so i want the dropdown has the item :
-)BOGOR
-)JADETABEK

. i'm a beginner at react native, so please help if i did a mistake

Comment: No mistake, you need to get the desired data and pass it to the component. I've provided an answer, I hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you want to use waits for a prop `data` array including objects key named `value` as your option values. So, you can create it, then pass it something like this (not tested) :

```
createData() {
  return this.state.data.map( el => ({value: el.Location}));
}

render() {
        const data = this.createData();
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Dropdown data={data} />
            </View>
        )
}
```

**Update after discussion on chat**

Somehow, `res.PilihLokasiResult.Lokasi` is coming as a JSON string. So using `JSON.parse` and setting the state like that solved the second problem:

```
this.setState({
    data: JSON.parse( res.PilihLokasiResult.Lokasi )
})
```

Comment: I've tried the .map function. it throw an error saying "this.state.map is not a function"

Comment: Of course, it says because it is `this.state.data.map` :) I've updated my answer.

Comment: hahaha now it says "TypeError: TypeError: cannot read property 'map' of undefined" :(

Comment: Are you sure you are the getting the result you posted here?

Comment: Just comment out or remove this line `const data = this.createData();` Then, add a `console.log(this.state)` right below the `render()` line. Then look the console for logs.

Comment: console.log(this.state) or console.log(this.state.data) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180167/discussion-between-devserkan-and-rondi).

Comment: now it works!! thanks devserkan for your help. as u suggested just put JSON.parse() to the response because my response is a String type not an array type..